# moveit setup assistant problem

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I have a problem I installed moveit (apt-get install ros-indigo-full) in indigo ros. When I try to start moveit_setup_assistant I have an error

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [moveit_setup_assistant/moveit_setup_assistant]: can't locate node [moveit_setup_assistant] in package [moveit_setup_assistant]
```

but if I write `source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash` it work's but i cannot load urdf files from my workspace and then I have this error

```
started roslaunch server http://lenovo-Lenovo-Z580:48193/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.20

NODES
  /
    moveit_setup_assistant (moveit_setup_assistant/moveit_setup_assistant)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [4680]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 0003089c-59ad-11e6-a798-9c4e363e21f8
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [4693]
started core service [/rosout]
process[moveit_setup_assistant-2]: started with pid [4700]
[rospack] Error: no package given
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ INFO] [1470251044.034022112]: Loaded origins robot model.
[ INFO] [1470251044.034098866]: Setting Param Server with Robot Description
[ INFO] [1470251044.038456612]: Robot semantic model successfully loaded.
[ INFO] [1470251044.038513275]: Setting Param Server with Robot Semantic Description
[ INFO] [1470251044.057449009]: Loading robot model 'origins'...
[ INFO] [1470251044.057519186]: No root joint specified. Assuming fixed joint
[rospack] Error: package 'sam_load_urdf_into_rviz' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1470251044.081150637]: Error retrieving file [package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/wozek_nowe.stl]: Package [sam_load_urdf_into_rviz] does not exist
[rospack] Error: package 'sam_load_urdf_into_rviz' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1470251044.105417166]: Error retrieving file [package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/podstawa_obrotowa.stl]: Package [sam_load_urdf_into_rviz] does not exist
[rospack] Error: package 'sam_load_urdf_into_rviz' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1470251044.130234290]: Error retrieving file [package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/czlon1_TOP.stl]: Package [sam_load_urdf_into_rviz] does not exist
[rospack] Error: package 'sam_load_urdf_into_rviz' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1470251044.155245446]: Error retrieving file [package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/czlon2_TOP.stl]: Package [sam_load_urdf_into_rviz] does not exist
[rospack] Error: package 'sam_load_urdf_into_rviz' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1470251044.179064495]: Error retrieving file [package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/nadgartek1.stl]: Package [sam_load_urdf_into_rviz] does not exist
[rospack] Error: package 'sam_load_urdf_into_rviz' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1470251044.201857911]: Error retrieving file [package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/nadgarstek2.stl]: Package [sam_load_urdf_into_rviz] does not exist
[ INFO] [1470251044.296414031]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[ INFO] [1470251044.296514461]: OpenGl version: 3 (GLSL 1.3).
[ INFO] [1470251044.438444256]: Loading robot model 'origins'...
[ INFO] [1470251044.438502480]: No root joint specified. Assuming fixed joint
[rospack] Error: package 'sam_load_urdf_into_rviz' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1470251044.463628224]: Error retrieving file [package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/wozek_nowe.stl]: Package [sam_load_urdf_into_rviz] does not exist
[rospack] Error: package 'sam_load_urdf_into_rviz' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1470251044.490362214]: Error retrieving file [package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/podstawa_obrotowa.stl]: Package [sam_load_urdf_into_rviz] does not exist
[rospack] Error: package 'sam_load_urdf_into_rviz' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1470251044.515006440]: Error retrieving file [package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/czlon1_TOP.stl]: Package [sam_load_urdf_into_rviz] does not exist
[rospack] Error: package 'sam_load_urdf_into_rviz' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1470251044.541040205]: Error retrieving file [package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/czlon2_TOP.stl]: Package [sam_load_urdf_into_rviz] does not exist
[rospack] Error: package 'sam_load_urdf_into_rviz' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1470251044.566688572]: Error retrieving file [package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/nadgartek1.stl]: Package [sam_load_urdf_into_rviz] does not exist
[rospack] Error: package 'sam_load_urdf_into_rviz' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1470251044.589428115]: Error retrieving file [package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/nadgarstek2.stl]: Package [sam_load_urdf_into_rviz] does not exist
[rospack] Error: package 'sam_load_urdf_into_rviz' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1470251044.615792109]: Error retrieving file [package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/wozek_nowe.stl]: Package [sam_load_urdf_into_rviz] does not exist
[ WARN] [1470251044.615909345]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/wozek_nowe.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1470251044.616027330]: Could not load model 'package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/wozek_nowe.stl' for link 'base_link': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/wozek_nowe.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ WARN] [1470251044.616103593]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/wozek_nowe.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1470251044.616164565]: Could not load model 'package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/wozek_nowe.stl' for link 'base_link': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/wozek_nowe.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[rospack] Error: package 'sam_load_urdf_into_rviz' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1470251044.640174257]: Error retrieving file [package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/nadgarstek2.stl]: Package [sam_load_urdf_into_rviz] does not exist
[ WARN] [1470251044.640278640]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/nadgarstek2.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1470251044.640350763]: Could not load model 'package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/nadgarstek2.stl' for link 'chwytak': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/nadgarstek2.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ WARN] [1470251044.640417334]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/nadgarstek2.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1470251044.640475820]: Could not load model 'package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/nadgarstek2.stl' for link 'chwytak': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/nadgarstek2.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[rospack] Error: package 'sam_load_urdf_into_rviz' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1470251044.664436607]: Error retrieving file [package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/czlon1_TOP.stl]: Package [sam_load_urdf_into_rviz] does not exist
[ WARN] [1470251044.664558444]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/czlon1_TOP.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1470251044.664632736]: Could not load model 'package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/czlon1_TOP.stl' for link 'czlon1': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/czlon1_TOP.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ WARN] [1470251044.664699324]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/czlon1_TOP.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1470251044.664761326]: Could not load model 'package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/czlon1_TOP.stl' for link 'czlon1': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/czlon1_TOP.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[rospack] Error: package 'sam_load_urdf_into_rviz' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1470251044.688725754]: Error retrieving file [package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/czlon2_TOP.stl]: Package [sam_load_urdf_into_rviz] does not exist
[ WARN] [1470251044.688833289]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/czlon2_TOP.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1470251044.688906230]: Could not load model 'package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/czlon2_TOP.stl' for link 'czlon2': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/czlon2_TOP.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ WARN] [1470251044.688976294]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/czlon2_TOP.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1470251044.689037233]: Could not load model 'package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/czlon2_TOP.stl' for link 'czlon2': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/czlon2_TOP.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[rospack] Error: package 'sam_load_urdf_into_rviz' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1470251044.713061650]: Error retrieving file [package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/nadgartek1.stl]: Package [sam_load_urdf_into_rviz] does not exist
[ WARN] [1470251044.713203876]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/nadgartek1.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1470251044.713310182]: Could not load model 'package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/nadgartek1.stl' for link 'nadgarstek': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/nadgartek1.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ WARN] [1470251044.713446951]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/nadgartek1.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1470251044.713568366]: Could not load model 'package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/nadgartek1.stl' for link 'nadgarstek': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/nadgartek1.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[rospack] Error: package 'sam_load_urdf_into_rviz' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1470251044.738767020]: Error retrieving file [package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/podstawa_obrotowa.stl]: Package [sam_load_urdf_into_rviz] does not exist
[ WARN] [1470251044.738891757]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/podstawa_obrotowa.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1470251044.738981630]: Could not load model 'package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/podstawa_obrotowa.stl' for link 'podstawka': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/podstawa_obrotowa.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ WARN] [1470251044.739064320]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/podstawa_obrotowa.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1470251044.739143364]: Could not load model 'package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/podstawa_obrotowa.stl' for link 'podstawka': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/podstawa_obrotowa.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ INFO] [1470251044.744666623]: Loading robot model 'origins'...
[ INFO] [1470251044.744720600]: No root joint specified. Assuming fixed joint
[rospack] Error: package 'sam_load_urdf_into_rviz' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1470251044.769319223]: Error retrieving file [package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/wozek_nowe.stl]: Package [sam_load_urdf_into_rviz] does not exist
[rospack] Error: package 'sam_load_urdf_into_rviz' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1470251044.793802685]: Error retrieving file [package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/podstawa_obrotowa.stl]: Package [sam_load_urdf_into_rviz] does not exist
[rospack] Error: package 'sam_load_urdf_into_rviz' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1470251044.818130899]: Error retrieving file [package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/czlon1_TOP.stl]: Package [sam_load_urdf_into_rviz] does not exist
[rospack] Error: package 'sam_load_urdf_into_rviz' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1470251044.841442902]: Error retrieving file [package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/czlon2_TOP.stl]: Package [sam_load_urdf_into_rviz] does not exist
[rospack] Error: package 'sam_load_urdf_into_rviz' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1470251044.864851154]: Error retrieving file [package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/nadgartek1.stl]: Package [sam_load_urdf_into_rviz] does not exist
[rospack] Error: package 'sam_load_urdf_into_rviz' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1470251044.889505015]: Error retrieving file [package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/nadgarstek2.stl]: Package [sam_load_urdf_into_rviz] does not exist
[ WARN] [1470251044.889922338]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/wozek_nowe.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1470251044.890012420]: Could not load model 'package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/wozek_nowe.stl' for link 'base_link': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/wozek_nowe.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ WARN] [1470251044.890073659]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/wozek_nowe.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1470251044.890133560]: Could not load model 'package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/wozek_nowe.stl' for link 'base_link': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/wozek_nowe.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ WARN] [1470251044.890254687]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/nadgarstek2.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1470251044.890317376]: Could not load model 'package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/nadgarstek2.stl' for link 'chwytak': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/nadgarstek2.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ WARN] [1470251044.890372491]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/nadgarstek2.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1470251044.890431045]: Could not load model 'package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/nadgarstek2.stl' for link 'chwytak': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/nadgarstek2.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ WARN] [1470251044.890545600]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/czlon1_TOP.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1470251044.890606067]: Could not load model 'package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/czlon1_TOP.stl' for link 'czlon1': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/czlon1_TOP.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ WARN] [1470251044.890659806]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/czlon1_TOP.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1470251044.890715516]: Could not load model 'package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/czlon1_TOP.stl' for link 'czlon1': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/czlon1_TOP.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ WARN] [1470251044.890826542]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/czlon2_TOP.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1470251044.890885271]: Could not load model 'package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/czlon2_TOP.stl' for link 'czlon2': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/czlon2_TOP.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ WARN] [1470251044.890938065]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/czlon2_TOP.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1470251044.890993213]: Could not load model 'package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/czlon2_TOP.stl' for link 'czlon2': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/czlon2_TOP.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ WARN] [1470251044.891103321]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/nadgartek1.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1470251044.891161839]: Could not load model 'package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/nadgartek1.stl' for link 'nadgarstek': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/nadgartek1.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ WARN] [1470251044.891213686]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/nadgartek1.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1470251044.891268504]: Could not load model 'package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/nadgartek1.stl' for link 'nadgarstek': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/nadgartek1.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ WARN] [1470251044.891372998]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/podstawa_obrotowa.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1470251044.891430646]: Could not load model 'package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/podstawa_obrotowa.stl' for link 'podstawka': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/podstawa_obrotowa.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ WARN] [1470251044.891483371]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/podstawa_obrotowa.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1470251044.891538455]: Could not load model 'package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/podstawa_obrotowa.stl' for link 'podstawka': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://sam_load_urdf_into_rviz/urdf/NOWE_STL/podstawa_obrotowa.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ INFO] [1470251044.921358451]: Loading Setup Assistant Complete
```

Do you know how to fix this problem? I was traying to remove and install again and nothing works...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241041/moveit-setup-assistant-problem/) by [mopsiu50](https://answers.ros.org/users/27673/mopsiu50/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-08-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on 2016-11-08**:
I have a same problem!!! help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you had **a partially built moveit package** in **your own** /root/catkin_ws directory earlier?

**If so,**
there is **no need to install from source** that usually causes problem for freshmen like me.
Be sure to **clean up the old stuff before catin_make**.

Follow the steps:

```
$ cd ~/catkin_ws %YOUR_WORK_PLACE%
$ rm -rf devel build
$ catkin_make
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

[I came across the similar question that has been solved just now, here is the link to my question and answer.](http://answers.ros.org/question/247531/moveit_setup_assistant-cannot-launch-node-of-type-in-indigo/)

---

Originally posted by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) with karma: 339 on 2016-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0